# Checking value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm brand new to html and JavaScript, I have this function on a button and I want the script to change my label to "Correct password" when the value of the input box is "greenapples42" It always says correct no matter what the input is though.

```js
function Gen() {
  var Val = document.getElementById("Pass").value
  var SpecPass = "greenapples42"
  if (Val = SpecPass) {
    document.getElementById("Label1").textContent = "Correct password"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Label1").textContent = "Incorrect password"
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="Pass" id="Label1"></label>
<input type="text" name="varTest" id="Pass" value="">
<button onclick="Gen()" style="border: 3px double black; background-color:lightblue">Check</button>
```

Comment: Seeing as you're new, learn that java != JavaScript

Comment: Next, learn that `=` is assignment, and `==` and `===` are comparison in JavaScript

Comment: haha i should have guessed with my knowledge of lua, thank you!